# Labeling a text and referencing it later

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to attach a label to a string and then refer to that string with a reference?

For example,

```
\labelText{This is a text that is also a tag}{label:text}
```

and then refer to this string with `\ref{label:text}` where the string will serve as a tag itself.

Why I need it? I am writing a pseudo code and using a command `go to #line number` but the line number might change if I insert extra line in the code.
With referencing this will be avoided.

Comment: With `\ref{label:text}` the text "This is a text that is also a tag" should appear, I assume?

Comment: do you know about `\hypertarget{label}{target caption}` and `\hyperlink{label}{link caption}` from `hyperref` package http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/hyperref/manual.html#x1-140004

Comment: @touhami: That's another possibility but does not replicate the text (and that's what's requested -- at least I've understood the question this way)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes you're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this? This writes the text explicitly to the `.aux` file and provides a hyperlink to it. Use `\nameref` to get the label content, not the label number (which is given by `\ref`)

With more information a better solution could be given.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
#1\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{\unexpanded{#1}}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]

\begin{center}
In \nameref{label:text} we have
\end{center}
\section{First} \label{firstsection}
\blindtext[5]
\labelText{This \textsc{is} a text that is also a tag}{label:text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It gives me error when adding some formatting in the tag: `\labelText{This {\sc is} a text that is also a tag}{label:text}`
Is it possible to accommodate this option in tags?

Comment: @FiboKowalsky: First of all: Don't use the **outdated** `\sc` command. Second: Of course the approach with writing will fail until `\unexpanded` or `\protected@write` is used. I'll change

Comment: @FiboKowalsky: See the update please!

Answer (score 12):

`\label` will refer to the current value of `\@currentlabel`; just use this feature.

```
\documentclass{article}

% for LaTeX before 2015 uncomment the two following lines
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\MakeRobust{\ref}

% for LaTeX between 2015 and 2021 uncomment the following line
%\MakeRobust{\ref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labeltext}[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \csname phantomsection\endcsname % in case hyperref is used
  \def\@currentlabel{#1}{\label{#2}}%
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec-test}

Some text and a textual label\labeltext{Some text in section~\ref{sec-test}}{try}

\section{Again}

Here it is: ``\ref{try}''

\end{document}
```

If your LaTeX kernel is before 2015/01/01, update it. Until you do, add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` in order to have `\MakeRobust` available. Making `\ref` robust is not needed if you load `hyperref`.

[image]

Comment: With TeX Live 2023, the second run gives an error `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`

Comment: @Stephen Fixed with recommendations for older LaTeX versions

Comment: Thank you!@egreg

Answer (score 2):

Adding a second, completely different answer that applies my `crossreftools` package (Needs version 0.6, from 
[DropBox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9b875cmrrnyl5j/crossreftools.0.6.tar.gz?dl=0))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}


\makeatletter


\def\labelText{%
  \@ifstar{\@labeltextstarred}{\@labeltext}
}
\newcommand{\@labeltextstarred}[2]{%
  \crtcrossreflabel*{#1}[#2]%
}

\newcommand{\@labeltext}[2]{%
  \crtcrossreflabel{#1}[#2]%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\labelText{Sample with holes}{label:text} \labelText*{and now for something completely different}{other:text}

In \crtlnameref{label:text} or \crtunameref{other:text} or \crtnameref{label:text}

\end{document}
```