# How to use normal label within a custom command for a definition of hypertarget?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to make a command that defines a `\hypertarget` with the target label (first argument of `\hypertarget`) by the contained `\label` and the target caption (second argument of `\hypertarget`) by its content.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\mytargetcommand[1]{?}

\begin{document}
\mytargetcommand{My content\label{tag}}
\ref{tag}
\end{document}
```

So this would output `My content` twice where the second references to the first.

Comment: I think, you need a different strategy here

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Yes, I thought I could use the the label redefinition but it did not work. Hope there is a way to do this as well. :)

Comment: `\ref{tag}` will not give `My content` however!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking rather for something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271064/31729

Comment: @Christian Hupfer No, I am really looking for a way to use the ordinary `\label` command while keeping the content and the label separate... `\mytargetcommand{Text\label{tag}}` -> `\hypertarget{tag}{Text}`

Comment: Why don't you use two parameters, text and label, directly?

Comment: @wilx I need to use the `\label` command from the gui (LyX). Is the problem that `\label` is inside of `\mytargetcommand`? I guess I could put it just after the command if that would help. Like `\mytargetcommand{Text}\label{tag}` -> `\hypertarget{tag}{Text}`

Comment: @Daniel: It's in fact a little bit tricky to cope with `#1\label`

Comment: @Christian Hupfer That is surprising that one cannot access both at the same time. Would a two argument command help? `\mytargetcommand{Text}{\label{tag}}` -> `\hypertarget{tag}{Text}`

Comment: Maybe something with @currentlabel. Sorry, this exceeds my LaTeX knowledge. (I guess that's why I am asking.)

Comment: @Daniel: See the possible answer, but I am not sure, it will work always

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there are better ways to split the `My content\label{tag}` stuff such that `\hypertarget` does not choke on `\label`: Use `\def\splitcmd#1\label#2` and a similar command that splits the with undelimited arguments (actually, `\label` is the argument delimiter here).

This uses a dummy counter and to refer to the text, use `\nameref` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
% Two helper commands --> get the text before \label
\def\splitcmd#1\label#2{%
  #1%
}
% Get the label tag
\def\splitcmdother#1\label#2{%
  #2%
}


\newcounter{localtagcntr}


  \newcommand\mytargetcommand[1]{%
    \edef\local@tag{\splitcmdother#1}%
    \edef\my@text{\splitcmd#1}%
    \refstepcounter{localtagcntr}%
    \def\@currentlabelname{\my@text}% Change the label content name
    \label{\local@tag}% Set the label
    \hypertarget{\local@tag}{\my@text}% 
  }

\makeatother
\begin{document}
Foostuff
\clearpage
\mytargetcommand{My content\label{tag}}
\ref{tag}

\clearpage
\hyperlink{tag}{Stuff}

\nameref{tag}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you were first:-)

Comment: Thanks. Okay, so one problem is that it depends on where the `\label` is inserted. If it is inserted not at the end of the argument of `mytargetcommand` it will not work. Also it does not work when `mytargetcommand` is used in, for example, labels of descriptions. These are unfortunately quite some drawback.

Comment: It is still puzzling to me why one cannot just get a handle to the  label in the current scope of the `\mytargetcommand`.

Comment: @Daniel: The drawback is coming from a wrong design -- your design, actually, sorry!

Comment: @Christian Hupfer. It would be helpful to know what exactly makes it wrong in LaTeX. Are labels not supposed to be inside commands?

Comment: @Daniel: One issue is, that there should be counter that is to be labelled, e.g. a section or a figure etc. This is not the case here. The other issue is just the splitting of the text, into `text` and `label` stuff. `hypertarget` chokes on the `\label` inside the text, mainly on expansion, I think

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I see. Yes, these weird design restraints are coming from the GUI. I was hoping that it's current functionality was sufficient given the rich features of LaTeX. But I guess the GUI+LaTeX cannot handle what I was after. By the way, what I am after is a command that creates the references as I explained. But it is not important that it uses `hypertarget`. But I guess that is not the problem.

Comment: @Daniel: Therefore I never use GUIs for LaTeX -- they can't reproduce any feature provided by TeX.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: One can always use plain latex within the gui, so that is no principled reason against GUIs.

Comment: @Daniel: Sure. I've learned LaTeX without such GUIs, however, so I don't need them. They restrict too much, in my opinion

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Again, I don't see the restriction. I just find GUIs helpful when writing, so I don't have to look at the commands all the time.