# Unwanted space after \labeltext with \nameref package

Tags: spacing, labels, nameref

I'm using the \nameref package and I need to obtain a labelled text within round brackets, but it adds some space before the right bracket, while it doesn't add space after the left bracket. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage{nameref}

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
#1\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  %\string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{#1}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}
  \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{\unexpanded{#1}}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}
}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


(\labelText{A}{label:textA})

\end{document}
```

How can I do to avoid the unwanted addition of space before the right bracket?

N.B. adding `\hspace{-xpt}` doesnt't works as the space added isn't fixed but depends on the type of letter.

Thank you!

Edit: I added the MWE

Comment: Well, I've gave an answer once defining something like `\labelText`, perhaps I've missed some `%` character, but it could be some totally different code -- and that's the point: Which code are you using? Please post the minimal version of your document that shows this issue!

Comment: So, how is `\labelText` defined?

Comment: Add `%` after `\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}`

Comment: Yes, it was one of my answers ;-) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/labeling-a-text-and-referencing-it-later -- Corrected it

Comment: Also at the end of the `\string` line, although it's not essential.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, ... and the O.P. used just that version of my answers with this approach that had the missing `%` ...

Comment: Yes, it is possible that I used that version from your answer :)