# Lower-case letter in \nameref

Tags: cross-referencing, nameref

I use this before `\begin{document}`:

```
\newcounter{mylabelcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
    #1\refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{\unexpanded{#1}}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

and then in document

```
\labelText{Sample with holes}{label:text}
```

and

```
The \nameref{label:text} features extensive number of...
```

What I want is to obtain sentence: The sample with holes features extensive number of....

I need the fist letter of the word sample in the sentence to be lower-case (minuscule), and the first letter in `\labelText{Sample with holes}` upper-case (majuscule)... so I need to use `\MakeLowercase` for the command `\nameref{label:text}`...

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can just replace `\unexpanded{#1}` by `\unexpanded{\MakeLowercase{#1}}`, but this may be not the best approach.  This feels like an XY problem.  What is the aim?

Comment: When using code from other posts you could at least refer to the answerer (in this it is me ;-): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271064/31729

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with \unexpanded{\MakeLowercase{#1}} ... and I´m sorry that I didn´t  refer to the answerer - I don´t know very well how everything works here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version with some modifications from my `crossreftools` package, the code will be added to that package as well.

Use either `\labelText` or `\labelText*` in order to show the text or just hide it and then apply `\lnameref` or `\unameref` for `lower` or `upper` case reference of the referenced text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}


\makeatletter

\def\first@up#1#2\relax{\uppercase{#1}#2}%
\def\first@low#1#2\relax{\lowercase{#1}#2}

\newcommand{\firstupper}[1]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\first@up#1\relax}%
\newcommand{\firstlower}[1]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\first@low#1\relax}%

\def\labelText{%
  \@ifstar{\@labeltextstarred}{\@labeltext}
}
\newcommand{\@labeltextstarred}[2]{%
  \crtcrossreflabel*{#1}[#2]%
}

\newcommand{\@labeltext}[2]{%
  \crtcrossreflabel{#1}[#2]%
}

\def\@lowercasesplitter#1#2#3#4#5\@nil{%
  \firstlower{#3}% get the 3rd argument
}

\def\@uppercasesplitter#1#2#3#4#5\@nil{%
  \firstupper{#3}% Get the 3rd. argument
}


\newcommand{\lowercasesplitter}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@lowercasesplitter#1\@nil%
}
\newcommand{\uppercasesplitter}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@uppercasesplitter#1\@nil%
}


\newcommand{\lnameref}[1]{%
  \crtifdefinedlabel{#1}{%
    \expandafter\lowercasesplitter\csname r@#1\endcsname%
  }{}%
}

\newcommand{\unameref}[1]{%
  \crtifdefinedlabel{#1}{%
    \expandafter\uppercasesplitter\csname r@#1\endcsname%
  }{}%
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\labelText{Sample with holes}{label:text} \labelText*{and now for something completely different}{other:text}

In \lnameref{label:text} or \unameref{other:text} we have

\end{document}
```

**Much shorter version** with the updated `crossreftools` (version 0.6) package (until the package appears on CTAN/TeXLive/MikTeX) you could use this [DropBox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9b875cmrrnyl5j/crossreftools.0.6.tar.gz?dl=0)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}


\makeatletter


\def\labelText{%
  \@ifstar{\@labeltextstarred}{\@labeltext}
}
\newcommand{\@labeltextstarred}[2]{%
  \crtcrossreflabel*{#1}[#2]%
}

\newcommand{\@labeltext}[2]{%
  \crtcrossreflabel{#1}[#2]%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\labelText{Sample with holes}{label:text} \labelText*{and now for something completely different}{other:text}

In \crtlnameref{label:text} or \crtunameref{other:text} we have

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `\lowercase` processing just before `\immediate\write`:

```
   \lowercase{\def\tmp{#1}}%
   \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{\unexpanded\expandafter{\tmp}}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}%
   }%
```

But I warn you. Your code is bad. If you will need to use page reference then you cannot use `\immediate\write`, because `\thepage` is expanded at the time of `\immediate`, i. e. at the time when TeX is not sure about right page number.

Comment: Děkuji za odpověď!