# Use \nameref to get text from a custom environment

Tags: hyperref, ref, nameref

I've got an own environment for requirements.
In my document I want to reference each requirement and get its text. If I use `\namref` I get only the name of the corresponding section. Can someone help me?

Here is a short example

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}




%% Requirement environment
\newcounter{requirement}
\renewcommand\therequirement{A\arabic{requirement}} 
\newcommand{\reqref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
\newenvironment{req}[1][]{
    \refstepcounter{requirement}
    \begin{list}{\textbf{A\arabic{requirement}}\label{#1}}{%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{10pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{35pt}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{40pt}\setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}%
        }\em\item}%
    {\end{list}}





\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{My Section}

\begin{req}[A10]
    Text First requirement...
\end{req}

\begin{req}[A20]
    Text First requirement...
\end{req}

\begin{req}[A30]
    Text First requirement...
\end{req}


Now I want to reference the requirement and the its text. \\
\nameref{A10}  \\
\nameref{A20} \\
\nameref{A30} \\


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please complete your code snippet to be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Try `\edef\@currentlablename{...}` after `\refstepcounter` and before `\label` in order to get `{...}` from `\nameref`.  You will need `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`.

Comment: To be clear, `\nameref{A10}` should return `Text First requirement...`, correct? Will you always want to use `\nameref` *after* the `requirement` environment you reference (never *before*)? Are you open to using a different interface? That is, not `\label`-`\nameref`?

Comment: @Werner yes `\nameref{A10}` should return  `Text First requirement...`. I would use `\nameref` only for this environment and I am open to use a different interface. I only need sometimes to reference the number of the requirement. For this i use `\ref`. In the above example `\ref{A10}` should return `A10`.

Comment: I also struggled with this problem, and solved it in a simple and elegant way with help from @u-fischer. You can see the details in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/237)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example uses [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ) to capture the contents of the `req` environment (in `\BODY`), which is written to the `.aux` in the same way regular `\label`s are written (by updating `\@currentlabel` before calling `\label`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref,environ}

\newcounter{requirement}
\renewcommand{\therequirement}{A\arabic{requirement}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reqref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\textref}[1]{\ref{t@#1}}
\NewEnviron{req}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{requirement}%
  \begin{list}{\textbf{\therequirement}\label{#1}}{%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{10pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{35pt}%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{40pt}\setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}%
    }\itshape\item
    \def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{t@#1}%
    \BODY
  \end{list}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{My Section}

\begin{req}{A10}
  Text first requirement\ldots
\end{req}

\begin{req}{A20}
  Text second requirement\ldots
\end{req}

\begin{req}{A30}
  Text third requirement\ldots
\end{req}

Now I want to reference the requirement and the its text: 
\textref{A10}

\end{document}
```

Note that writing content to the `.aux` is fragile, as everything is expanded. As such, there may be some cases where you need to `\protect` whatever you write within the body of the `req` environment.

In this example, I've made the argument of `req` mandatory since you're using it as a `\label`. This `\label` has to be unique, and leaving it empty (or missing, in the case of an optional argument) would result in duplicate `\label`s.

Finally, I've changed the interface to `\textref` using the same label supplied to `req`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick and dirty way to get the text with `\nameref`. Therefor I use the solution from here:

[Labeling a text and referencing it later](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/labeling-a-text-and-referencing-it-later)

Here is the complete doc:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcounter{requirementtextcounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
    #1\refstepcounter{requirementtextcounter}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{\unexpanded{#1}}}{requirementtextcounter.\number\value{requirementtextcounter}}{}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother


\newcounter{requirement}
\renewcommand\therequirement{A\arabic{requirement}} 
\newcommand{\reqref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
\newenvironment{req}[1][]{
    \refstepcounter{requirement}
    \begin{list}{\textbf{A\arabic{requirement}}\label{#1}}{%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{10pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{35pt}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{40pt}\setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}%
        }\em\item}%
    {\end{list}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{My Section}

\begin{req}[A10]
    \labelText{Text First requirement...}{AT10}
\end{req}

\begin{req}[A20]
    Text First requirement...
\end{req}

\begin{req}[A30]
    Text First requirement...
\end{req}


Now I want to reference the requirement and the its text. \\
\nameref{AT10}



\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Don't add the example as answer, edit your question instead.