# Reference content inside custom environment

Tags: environments, exam, body

Been racking my brain on this problem, not sure what I'm doing wrong. This code is highly based off of this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506480/208131) but something isnt clicking. The goal is to be able to reference the contents of the solution environment later in my code.

Here is what im working with:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{sol}{
\begin{solution}
\def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{solt:\thequestion}
\BODY
\end{solution}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This is a question

\begin{sol}
My solution
\end{sol}

\begin{choices}
\choice 8
\choice 1
\choice 3
\choice 4
\end{choices}

\end{questions}


The first solution is:\\
\ref{solt:1}

\end{document}
```

When I run this, I receive an invalid reference. Any pointers as to what i may be doing incorrectly?

Comment: That was my bad. I've updated the post with the complete code. Yes i would like to generate the entire solution. In this case, it should display "My solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not typeset so your label is never generated in the `.aux` file, I think you intended

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{sol}{%
\def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{solt:\thequestion}%
\begin{solution}%
\BODY
\end{solution}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This is a question

\begin{sol}
My solution
\end{sol}

\begin{choices}
\choice 8
\choice 1
\choice 3
\choice 4
\end{choices}

\end{questions}


The first solution is:\\
\ref{solt:1}

\end{document}
```

However using an a `\label` with an automatically generated key seems dangerous, any edit to the file will mean the question gets a new number so the `\ref` will then refer a different question with no warning. It would be more in the spirit of `\label`/`\ref` to give your `sol` environment an argument so you supply a name to use in the `\label` which you could then also use in `\ref`.

Comment: Thank you!! Ill definitely switch up the labeling too

Comment: Thank you for this answer it's so useful, but how is it possible to hide sol environment?

Comment: @tstt  define it as `\NewEnviron{sol}{}`

Comment: Could you look at this question? Thank you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700356/make-hint-to-use-in-another-chapter?noredirect=1#comment1741112_700356