# Reference previously defined environment content later on in a tex file

Tags: expansion

### Question

What would be the best way to reference previously defined environment content later on in a tex file? Specifically content that can include other latex commands and not just text?

Related: [Labeling a text and referencing it later](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/labeling-a-text-and-referencing-it-later) (Text only)

### The Goal

Create a separate page for just the exam solutions.

### Implementation

To accomplish this I created a new environment `sol` that wrapped the `solution` environment native to the `exam` docclass. This wrapper then created a label for the solutions body content which I would use later on to reference.

The sol environment:

```latex
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{sol}{%
\def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{solt:\thequestion}%
\begin{solution}%
\protect\BODY
\end{solution}%
}
\makeatother
```

I would then define my questions and their solutions:

```latex
\begin{questions}

\begin{question}
Test Question

\begin{sol}
Test Solution
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{image.png}
\end{sol}
\end{question}

\end{questions}
```

And finally print the solutions using a custom command that would look through each question, and find its labelled solution:

```latex
\newcommand\printsolutions{%
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\thequestion}} \do {%
\def\x{##1}
\noindent
\x) ~\ref{solt:\x}\\
\\
}
\end{multicols*}
}
```

All together, there are four files:

- index.tex which holds the configuration and the includes
- questions.tex which holds the questions
- solutions.tex which holds the solutions
- index-solutions.tex which is used to compile the solutions only into a pdf

index.tex

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{sol}{%
\def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{solt:\thequestion}%
\begin{solution}%
\protect\BODY
\end{solution}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\printsolutions{%
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\thequestion}} \do {%
\def\x{##1}
\noindent
\x) ~\ref{solt:\x}\\
\\
}
\end{multicols*}
}

\begin{document}

\include{questions}
\include{solutions}

\end{document}
```

questions.tex

```latex
\begin{questions}

\begin{question}
Test Question

\begin{sol}
Test Solution
\protect\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{image.png}
\end{sol}
\end{question}
\begin{questions}
```

solutions.tex

```latex
\section*{\centering Solutions}

\printsolutions
```

index-solutions.tex

```latex
\includeonly{solutions}
\input{index}
```

### The Problem

This approach worked for 90% of the cases but would fail when the \BODY argument contains elements such as the \includegraphics command. If I protect the \includegraphics command, it works perfectly. I'm guessing because it doesn't expand the includegraphics command immediately.

Since I can't always know what will be the contents of the \BODY, I cant manually go through and set the \protect on troublesome commands such as the \includegraphics. Is there a better way to get around this?

Comment: \@currentlabel should certainly not be \BODY. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: you can save the body of an environment on a file to use later (see endnotes and similar packages) but you shouldn't use `\label` to do that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Later on in the tex file i reference a specific solution. So what I was doing was labeling it when its defined and then referencing that label later.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you mentioned using another way to achieve this workflow? Briefly looking into endnotes doesn't seem like the way to go, but ill read into it some more!

Comment: you haven't really given any indication of the workflow, or why you need to write it to a file, do you need forward references?

Comment: Ah sorry. I use the information to generate a "solutions only" section later on in the file, where i list all the solutions that where defined previously

Comment: Well, so it seems that no forward references are needed, which implies that you can probably store what you need to save in macros (possibly with dynamic names constructed using `\csname` ... `\endcsname`) and simply use the macros in the end to access the saved contents. Now, I believe you mostly need to give a short and clear description of the expected input syntax and output.

Comment: I updated the question description to hopefully be clearer. Its not the shortest, but i was trying to give a proper overview

Comment: Any suggestions based on the updated description?

Comment: I wrote an answer because I remembered and came back to this question, but please note that I didn't receive any notification, since you didn't address me with @frougon. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `\protect` helped is that `\label` uses `\protected@write` to write the “protected expansion“ of `\@currentlabel` to the `.aux` file. However, as you figured out, many things would need to be protected with this approach; thus, it is rather impractical.

Storing the solutions inside macros can be a successful approach, but it entails one tricky aspect: in your input, the `sol` environment is embedded in `question`, itself embedded in `questions`, and in the “only printing solutions” use case, you don't want to print the question text. So, in that case (which is when `\ifmyPrintEverything` is false in my example), I define the `questions` environment so that it defines the `question` environment to ignore everything until it finds `\begin{sol}`. This has to be done using recursion, because one can't use braces with catcodes 1 or 2 in tokens following delimited arguments when defining macros, AFAIK (IOW: I can't simply use `\begin{sol}` as a macro argument delimiter, but using `\begin` is fine; one “just” needs to check whether `{sol}` follows and, if not, recurse).

The following code works with a simple structure as in your example: only one `sol` environment as the last thing in the body of a `question`, and certainly no `sol` environment in `subquestions`, etc. It's a bit stupid and won't work if you have a `question` environment that doesn't end with its `sol` environment. I hope this helps anyway.

common.tex:

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Borrow \int_step_inline:nnn from expl3
\cs_new_eq:NN \intstepinline \int_step_inline:nnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newif\ifprintSolutionsmode     % initially false
\newtoks\mytoks

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{sol}{%
  \mytoks=\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \csxdef{my@sol@\number\value{question}}{\the\mytoks}%
  \unless\ifprintSolutionsmode
    \begin{solution}
      \BODY
    \end{solution}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\printsolutions{%
  \begin{multicols*}{2}
    \intstepinline{1}{\number\value{question}}{%
      \noindent ##1) \csuse{my@sol@##1}\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
    }%
  \end{multicols*}
}

\begin{document}

\ifmyPrintEverything
  \printSolutionsmodefalse
\else
  \renewenvironment{questions}
    {\newenvironment{question}{\refstepcounter{question}\@my@skip@question}{}}
    {}
  \long\def\@my@skip@question#1\begin#2{%
    \ifstrequal{#2}{sol}{\begin{sol}}{\@my@skip@question}%
  }%
  \printSolutionsmodetrue
\fi

\input{questions}\newpage
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

questions.tex:

```latex
\begin{questions}
  \begin{question}
    Test Question.

    \begin{sol}
      Test Solution.
      \includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
    \end{sol}
  \end{question}
  \begin{question}
    This is another question.
    \begin{sol}
      Solution of the second question. \textbf{Non-expandable stuff}
      \def\zzz{is fine}\zzz.
    \end{sol}
  \end{question}
\end{questions}
```

start-solutions.tex:

```latex
\newif\ifmyPrintEverything
\myPrintEverythingfalse

\input{common}
```

start-all.tex:

```latex
\newif\ifmyPrintEverything
\myPrintEverythingtrue

\input{common}
```

Compiling `start-all.tex` yields:

[image]

Compiling `start-solutions.tex` yields:

[image]