# Change the label display value

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I have a custom command to display pseudocodes using `tcolorbox`. The `\newtcblisting` command creates a custom counter to display the boxes. I'm trying to reference the pseudocodes somewhere in the document showing this custom counter but I only managed to show the chapter counter using `\ref`.

Here's a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[
      colorlinks=true,
]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,list inside=mypseudocodes]{pseudocodeV1}[3][]{%
  list entry={\thesection.\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2},
  title={Pseudocode \thesection.\thetcbcounter\label{pseudocode:#3}: #2},
  listing options={tabsize=2,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true},
  listing only,
  enhanced,
  #1
}


\newtcblisting[auto counter,list inside=mypseudocodes]{pseudocodeV2}[3][]{%
  list entry={\thesection.\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2},
  title={Pseudocode \thesection.\thetcbcounter\def\@currentlabel{Custom ref Text}{\label{pseudocode:#3}}: #2},
  listing options={tabsize=2,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true},
  listing only,
  enhanced,
  #1
}

\tcblistof[\section*]{mypseudocodes}{List of Pseudocodes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Pseudocodes}

\section{Test1}
PseudocodeV1: \ref{pseudocode:code} \\
\noindent
PseudocodeV2: \ref{pseudocode:code2} \\

\section{Test2}

\begin{pseudocodeV1}{
   My Title
}{code}
a = 1;
a = 2;
\end{pseudocodeV1}

\section{T1}


\begin{pseudocodeV2}{
   My Title
}{code2}
a = 1;
a = 2;
\end{pseudocodeV2}

\end{document}
```

Anyone knows why the command `\def\@currentlabel{}{}` isnt working or can suggest any workarround?

I've got the `\def\@currentlabel{}{}` suggestion from: [Labeling a text and referencing it later](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271062/labeling-a-text-and-referencing-it-later)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `\makeatletter` is missing (before the `\newtcblisting`).

Comment: I don't think that you want `\ref{pseudocode:code2}` to print “Custom ref Text“, do you?

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. That fixed the issue!

Comment: Yeah @egreg. It was intended for demonstration purposes. In practice, it should be the figure reference number

Comment: In that case, related reading is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/107497

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by adding `\makeatletter` before `\newtcblisting`!
Credit to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for the solution in the comments.

The code below illustrates the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[
      colorlinks=true,
]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\newtcblisting[auto counter,list inside=mypseudocodes]{pseudocode}[3][]{%
  list entry={\thesection.\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2},
  title={Pseudocode \thesection.\thetcbcounter\def\@currentlabel{\thesection.\thetcbcounter}{\label{pseudocode:#3}}: #2},
  listing options={tabsize=2,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true},
  listing only,
  enhanced,
  #1
}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,list inside=mypseudocodes]{pseudocodeWText}[4][]{%
  list entry={\thesection.\protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}#2},
  title={Pseudocode \thesection.\thetcbcounter\def\@currentlabel{Some Custom Text: #4}{\label{pseudocode:#3}}: #2},
  listing options={tabsize=2,escapeinside=||,mathescape=true},
  listing only,
  enhanced,
  #1
}

\makeatother

\tcblistof[\section*]{mypseudocodes}{List of Pseudocodes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Pseudocodes}

\section{Test1}
Pseudocode: \ref{pseudocode:code1} \\
Pseudocode: \ref{pseudocode:code2} \\

\section{Test2}

\section{T1}


\begin{pseudocode}{
   My Title
}{code1}
a = 1;
a = 2;
\end{pseudocode}


\begin{pseudocodeWText}{
   My Title
}{code2}{Display Text}
a = 1;
a = 2;
\end{pseudocodeWText}




\end{document}
```

[image]